# Internet Explorer & fire fox cannot display the webpage

Tags: asp.net, browser

I try to open my page in Internet Explorer and Firefox but they can't display the webpage.
But I can open it in Opera and internal web browser. The address is like below:

```
http://localhost:14254/WebSite18/Default.aspx
```

Comment: Err...now, I don't think that's a problem of asp. Or any programming problem at all. Maybe something about your configuration is off?

Comment: please explain more, what can i do for doing on the configuration.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: in internet explorer i get (Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage) and in the fire fox i get (problem loading page)

Answer (score 1):

This will help.

Solution 1 for firefox: Add a firebug plugin in firefox and open the firebug and click on console. Now load your url. If there are any errors it will show in firebug console.

Solution 2: In IE, load the page and hit F12. This will open IE debugger. Click on Start Start debugging, this will refresh your page and you should see any errors in the IE debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Check your proxy settings for both IE and Firefox.  Both browsers should ignore your proxy server (if you have one) on local requests but the settings can be complicated and might be setup to force proxy calls even on local.

Does the page render in Google Chrome?

Comment: it does not render in google chrome also, just will be render in opera.